# how to send request using wsdl generated code (jax-ws) in netbeans

Tags: java, wsdl

Hai need help i am try to create wsdl client with step : right click in my project--->New -----> web service client ---> and i am chose my existing wsdl file in my computer,and then i got generated code in my project like on the picture below and got some warning in output console, how to use the generated code to send request to server ??? and about output console,do am i wrong when i am import wsdl file to the project??

here is piece of my code generated :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ExecutePrepaidStatusRq", propOrder = {
    "msisdnDealer",
    "msisdnSP",
    "username",
    "password",
    "switchId",
    "merchantId"
})
public class ExecutePrepaidStatusRq {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String msisdnDealer;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String msisdnSP;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String username;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String password;
    protected String switchId;
    protected String merchantId;
```

[image]

here is my error message :

```
parsing WSDL...

[WARNING] EmptyTargetNamespace: In schema document 'http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2', the value of the 'targetNamespace' attribute cannot be an empty string.
  line 1 of http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'types:Header' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
  line 7 of http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'types:PrepaidStatusRs' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
  line 8 of http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq": more than one part bound to body
  line 175 of file:/C:/Users/Achilles/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ClientPrepaidXL/xml-resources/web-service-references/cpCustomerOnBoarding/wsdl/cpCustomerOnBoarding.wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "ExecutePrepaidStatusRq": more than one part bound to body
  line 186 of file:/C:/Users/Achilles/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ClientPrepaidXL/xml-resources/web-service-references/cpCustomerOnBoarding/wsdl/cpCustomerOnBoarding.wsdl

[WARNING] Port "PublicEP" does not contain any usable operations
  line 129 of file:/C:/Users/Achilles/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ClientPrepaidXL/xml-resources/web-service-references/cpCustomerOnBoarding/wsdl/cpCustomerOnBoarding.wsdl

[WARNING] Service "Service" does not contain any usable ports. try running wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 128 of file:/C:/Users/Achilles/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ClientPrepaidXL/xml-resources/web-service-references/cpCustomerOnBoarding/wsdl/cpCustomerOnBoarding.wsdl

Generating code...
clientprepaidxl\ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq.java
clientprepaidxl\ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRqResponse.java
```

and here is my wsdl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xl.co.id/GenericFault/V1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xl.co.id/esb/payloads/cpCustomerOnBoarding/V1.0" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.example.com/1428655888834" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xl.co.id/SOAR/Component/HeaderRequest/V1_0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.example.com/1428655888834">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.xl.co.id/esb/payloads/cpCustomerOnBoarding/V1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xl.co.id/esb/payloads/cpCustomerOnBoarding/V1.0">
            <xs:complexType name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:msisdnDealer"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:msisdnSP"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:Name"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:IdType"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:IdNumber"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:Street1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:POB"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:DOB"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:OptIn"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:username"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:password"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:secCode"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:merchantId"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:Street2"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:City"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:Province"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:Postcode"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:Gender"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:Channel"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:switchId"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:Status"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:msisdnDealer"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:msisdnSP"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:username"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:password"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:switchId"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:merchantId"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="PrepaidStatusRs">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:msisdnSP"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:PrepaidStatus"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:respCode"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:respMessage"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Channel" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq" type="ns1:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq"/>
            <xs:element name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs" type="ns1:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs"/>
            <xs:element name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq" type="ns1:ExecutePrepaidStatusRq"/>
            <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="IdNumber" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="IdType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="OptIn" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="POB" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Postcode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="PrepaidStatus" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="PrepaidStatusRs" type="ns1:PrepaidStatusRs"/>
            <xs:element name="Province" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Street1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Street2" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="merchantId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msisdnDealer" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msisdnSP" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="respCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="respMessage" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="secCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="switchId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:hr="http://schemas.xl.co.id/SOAR/Component/HeaderRequest/V1_0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xl.co.id/SOAR/Component/HeaderRequest/V1_0">
            <xs:complexType name="Header">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="hr:ReqID"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="HeaderRequestType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="applicationID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="applicationSubID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="encryptionKey" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="encryptedText" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="touchpoint" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="msisdn" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="serviceID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IMEI" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CGI" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IMSI" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="hr:Header"/>
            <xs:element name="HeaderRequest" type="hr:HeaderRequestType"/>
            <xs:element name="ReqID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:genFault="http://schemas.xl.co.id/GenericFault/V1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xl.co.id/GenericFault/V1.0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>MsgCode = ErrorCode, e.g. Taken from Error Code System -&gt; BW-JDBC-100031
Message = ErrorMessage, e.g. Taken from Error Message - &gt; JDBC Connection Time Out
Process Stack = Hierarcy processes
Stack Trace = BW Stack Trace
Fault Actor  (Optional)
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType name="GenericFault">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MsgCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProcessStack" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StackTrace" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FaultActor" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="GenericFault" type="genFault:GenericFault"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:service name="Service">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:PublicEPBinding" name="PublicEP">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:11111/BusinessServices/cpCustomerOnBoarding/V1.0"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <wsdl:portType name="PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs"/>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:GenericFault" name="fault1"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ExecutePrepaidStatusRq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:PrepaidStatusRs"/>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:GenericFault" name="fault1"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="PublicEPBinding" type="tns:PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body parts="Header ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body parts="Header ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body parts="Header ExecutePrepaidStatusRq" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body parts="Header PrepaidStatusRs" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:message name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq">
        <wsdl:part element="ns0:Header" name="Header"/>
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq" name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs">
        <wsdl:part element="ns0:Header" name="Header"/>
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs" name="ExecutePrepaidRegistrationRs"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GenericFault">
        <wsdl:part element="ns2:GenericFault" name="Fault"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq">
        <wsdl:part element="ns0:Header" name="Header"/>
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:ExecutePrepaidStatusRq" name="ExecutePrepaidStatusRq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="PrepaidStatusRs">
        <wsdl:part element="ns0:Header" name="Header"/>
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:PrepaidStatusRs" name="PrepaidStatusRs"/>
    </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Please share error message as text and not as an image!

Comment: oke i have edited my question

Comment: Can you show us the wsdl... Maybe the port definition is missing for the service. I cannot find the service and port classes in your screenshot!

Comment: where should i paste my wsdl ?? if i paste here is too long

Comment: i have adding my wsdl file in my question, please help..